# data must of vector type, was NULL

Tags: r

So, I am trying to convert each string a list like this to a string,

```
mylist

# [[1]]
# [1] "abc" "000"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a00" "ac0" "bcc"

....................
```

Now, I am trying to apply the function

```
mylist <- lapply(mylist, matrix, nrow=1) # convert each string to matrix
```

But this shows the error that,

> Error in FUN(X[[202L]], ...) :    'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'`.

It works with strings having only `1's` and `0's` but doesn't work with characters

Comment: The error message provides you with a place to start debugging. What does mylist[[202]] contain? Your description of what you are trying to do is not clear.

Comment: @sarah I replied to your new question `Comparing two dataframes and outputting unique values` and after 5 min, the thread just disappeared??

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs when there are missing or blank list elements at least one index. We can recreate this error by purposely creating a list with an empty element:

```
mylist <- list(c("abc","000"),
               c("a00","ac0","bcc"),
               c(),
               c("a00","ac0","bcc"))

lapply(mylist, matrix, nrow=1)
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'data' must be of a vector type, was
>   'NULL'

To fix the above error, we can simply remove the blank elements in our list by running code that subsets the list by elements that only have a length greater than zero, like this:

```
mylist <- mylist[lapply(mylist,length)>0]
```

Now that there aren't any empty elements in our list, we can rerun lapply(mylist, matrix, nrow=1), which will successfully convert each element to a matrix format.

```
lapply(mylist, matrix, nrow=1)

[[1]]
     [,1]  [,2] 
[1,] "abc" "000"

[[2]]
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "a00" "ac0" "bcc"

[[3]]
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "a00" "ac0" "bcc"
```

Comment: @sarah - Hi, are you still looking for an answer to this question or does this provide a solution? If this was helpful, please select it as a solution to help the community know it's been solved and to help others find their answer even faster. Thanks.